# Get offfset for timezone without Daylight Savings Time

Tags: php, datetime

How can I get the offset for a DateTime without Daylight Savings time? I can get the offset like this:

```
<?php
  $winter = new DateTime('2010-12-21', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
  $summer = new DateTime('2008-06-21', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

  echo $winter->getOffset() . "\n";
  echo $summer->getOffset() . "\n";
?>
```

But if I understand it correctly, it outputs the offset with DST. I know we can check if DST is in effect like this:

```
<?php
  $timezone = new DateTimeZone("Europe/London");
  $transitions = $timezone->getTransitions();
  print_r(array_slice($transitions, 0, 3));
?>
```

I also see there is the `IntlTimeZone::getOffset` but how can I use this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're going to use that information for? The offset is what it is for that location at that time. "Without DST" doesn't make a lot of sense in general, but maybe it does if you clarify what you need it for.

Comment: I need to calculate the sunset and sunrise at a particular location. I am using date_sunset() and date_sunrise(). I can find out the offset of the timezone at that location and use it as a parameter for date_sunset() and date_sunrise() but it is for a flight, and they pass multiple timezones but flight duration stays the same, I am incrementing flight time+1 and finding out sunrise and sunset at that location and at that time.

Comment: If you know the timezone you want it in, I'd rather use the `SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP` return mode and format that timestamp to the desired timezone…!?

Comment: But when I do format it to the desired timezone, it will include the DST won't it?

Comment: It will include it if necessary. If DST is currently in effect in New York, then any time there should be formatted including DST.

Comment: I see. Is there a way however to get the offset without accounting for DST?

Comment: "America/New_York" is a *timezone* which "bundles" offsets and switches between them based on the time of year. Specifically, it's either EST or EDT. *Those* have specific fixed offsets. So… get the offset of one of those two? Which will be a fixed number anyway?

Comment: That seems like a good approach, let me have a go at it :) Thank you so much